# Node error : " Error: Cannot find module 'node:console' "

Tags: node.js, npm

I run the code `node api.js` to start my REST API, but it returns this error. I found no similar error on google, does anyone knows what's wrong? Thanks.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'node:console'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pi/projects/Tese/API/sensor_scheme.js:2:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pi/projects/Tese/API/api.js:4:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Check line 4 of your `api.js` file?

Comment: You're probably doing an import/require of `'node:console'` on line 4

Comment: I wasn't, the first lines were 

var restify = require('restify');

const server = restify.createServer({
    name: 'Server',
    version: '1.0.0'
});
const connectDB = require('./connection');
connectDB();


server.use(restify.plugins.acceptParser(server.acceptable));
server.use(restify.plugins.queryParser());
server.use(restify.plugins.bodyParser());

Comment: confusing comment sorry. Anyway, I re-wrote the code in other file and the error was gone. Really weird stuff. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @fortunee you were right after all.

Comment: Alright, I'm gonna post that as the answer and you can upvote/accept it. Is that ok? @EscagaSeen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same error. Tried re-writing the code to other file, still had the error.
Was wierd. 
I noticed the line:
`const { Console } = require("node:console");` 
added to my file at the start on compilation. 
**Reason:** 
There was a place I misspelled Console with capital C and so while compilation it got intrepreted as module and thus the line was added at the start.

**Solution:** 
Once I corrected the Console to console and removed the above line of code, it worked properly for me.